# Run shell(bash, zsh, sh...) as a child process in node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, express, sockets, socket.io

I'm making an online shell to access my computer from another computer or device. I can run any program, sending and receiving stdio data using socket.io. I run the programs using execFile() from child_process. The problem is that, when I try to run bash, sh, zsh, csh or any other shell it just doesn't work, no error message or anything. How can I run a shell as a child process in node.js(prefer using execFile, but it doesn't matter)? This is the code I'm using:

Server:

```
let fs = require("fs");
let socket = require("socket.io");
let express = require("express");
let stringio = require("@rauschma/stringio");
let childprocess = require("child_process");
let app = express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
let server = app.listen(3000);

console.log("Server running!");
let io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on("connection", connectionListener);

function connectionListener(socket) {
  console.log("New client!");
  let child = childprocess.execFile("bash", ["test.sh"], {
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]
  }); 
  socket.on("stdin-packet", sendtochild);
  function sendtochild(packet) {
    child.stdin.write(packet.rawtext);
  }
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    let packet = {
      rawtext: data.toString()
    };
    socket.emit("stdout-packet", packet);
    console.log("Packet sended!");
  });
}
```

Client:

```
let socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");

function TerminalScreen(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.chars = "";

  this.print = function(text) {
    let isansi = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
      if (text.charCodeAt(i) == 27) {
        isansi = true;
      } else if (text.charAt(i) == 'm' || text.charAt(i) == 'K' || text.charAt(i) == 'H' || text.charAt(i) == 'f' || text.charAt(i) == 'J') {
        if (isansi) {
          isansi = false;
        } else {
          this.chars += text.charAt(i);
        }
      } else if (!isansi) {
        this.chars += text.charAt(i);
      }
    }
    this.chars = this.chars.replace("\n", "<br>");
  }

  this.clear = function() {
    this.chars = "";
  }

  this.update = function() {
    document.getElementById("terminal-div").innerHTML = this.chars;
  }
}

let screen = new TerminalScreen();

socket.on("stdout-packet", packetReceived);

function packetReceived(packet) {
  screen.print(packet.rawtext);
  screen.update();
}

document.onkeypress = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  let packet = {
    rawtext: String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)
  };
  socket.emit("stdin-packet", packet);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, because bash detects it's not running in a pseudo terminal (pty), it assumes it is running non-interactively. You can either create a full pseudo terminal (which things like `expect` or `ssh` will do), or you may be able to force it with the `-i` flag.

Comment: The -i flag? If you mean running bash -i, it doesn't work, it instead shows the bash terminal and hides the node console. And how can I make my own pseudo terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [node-pty](https://npmjs.com/package/node-pty) package works for me.